# Is there a way to implement Django templates in a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django form where admins create user-specific pages, and I want admins to add `{{username}}` as input in the form so that when the content of the created page is rendered to a user the tag `{{username}}` becomes the username.

Here's what I have tried so far;

`views.py:`

```
class CreateCampaignView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('Portal:login')
    template_name = 'Portal/PostForm.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Portal:feed')

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.Subject = form.cleaned_data['Subject']
        form.instance.Text_content = form.cleaned_data['Text_content']
        form.instance.HTML_content = form.cleaned_data['HTML_content']
        template = form.instance.HTML_content
        
        context = Context(dict({'username':'xxxx', 'email':'Test@email.com'}))
        template.render(context)

        return super().form_valid(form, **kwargs)
```

This method is returning an error "str object does not have render", because HTML_content is a Text_filed in `forms.py` and I couldn't find a workaround to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `Template` for the data from the form, so:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

template = Template(form.cleaned_data['HTML_content'])
context = Context({'username': 'xxxx'}) # instead of xxxx, users.objects.filter(username='John')
rendered: str = template.render(context)
```

Comment: Following your answer I did exactly the following:


`template = Template(form.cleaned_data['HTML_content'])`
 
`context = Context(dict({'username':'xx', 'email':'xx@xx.com'}))`

`rendered: str = template.render(context)`

but I am still getting `'str' object has no attribute 'render'`

Comment: @Farhan: can you share the full view/method together with the traceback? Did you use `template = Template(...)` and did not assign anything else to `template`? Please *edit* the question.

Comment: I've just edited my question

Comment: Farhan, again, you should wrap the content in a `Template` object, so `template = Template(form.instance.HTML_content)`.